# How do I make my CSS Drop-down menu work?

Tags: css

I was trying to make dropdown menu using only css, however it doesn't work in my case.
It's kinda working when I don't put `position:absolute` at `.dropdown_content` in CSS, but even when I do that, dropdown doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Game order</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown_content">
        <a href="#">Half-life</a>
        <a href="#">Half-life 2</a>
        <a href="#">Half-life EP1</a>
        </div>
        </div>  
        <li><a href="#">Portal series</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Half Life Alyx</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown_content {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 160px;
  display:none;
}

.dropdown_content a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can **only** have `li` as children.

Comment: I wrapped div in li, no changes.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple, I have reduced your code to a bare minimum. 
I'm not sure exactly how you want it to look, but here's a possible solution.

When making css only menu's I try to stick to a nested list of `<ul>` and `<li>`'s. 
This makes it clearer to read, and keeps the semantics in order. 
Ther is no need for container divs within. (like the `<div class="dropdown_content">` in your code)

The HTML is a nested list. Initially we hide the nested ul, and only show it when it's parent is hovered over. By using `.dropDown li:hover>ul` you only target the ul that is DIRECTLY under the hovered li. That way you dan nest as deep as you want.

```css
.dropDown ul {
  display: none;  
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.dropDown li:hover>ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dropDown">
    <li><a href="#">Game order</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Half-life</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Half-life 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Half-life EP1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portal series</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Half Life Alyx</a></li>
    <li>deeper nesting
      <ul>
        <li>level 1</li>
        <li>more here
          <ul>
            <li>level 2</li>
            <li>more here
              <ul>
                <li>level 3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```